# About ActiveDirectory IIS_IUSRS and USERS Group

Tags: active-directory

I have two PC.
For development PC and Test Server PC.
I login Development PC use KJM/MyUser.
And login Test Server use CDM/Administrator.

I deploy a web site. This have to get user name and domain.
If i access this site from development PC.
I get CDM/guest. It is wrong. I want to get KJM/MyUser.

I surveied web. And now I expect that this problem concern active directory.

It permit access CDM/USERS that folder of server include deployed website files.
If i Change setting to deny CDM/USERS. I can't access from development pc.
And I added permit access user IIS_IUSRS. and tested that deny access IIS_IUSRS.
as a result I could access from development pc.

So now. I expect that If i add access permition KJM/MyUser on server folder, i can get KJM/MyUser instead CDM/guest.(just my expectation).
I think KJM/MyUser have not authorization to access server's folder. So try to Access the folder with IIS_IUSRS. I think It is the reason return CDM/guest to me.

It is just my expectation.But i can't Check about this because. I can't add permition KJM Domain User on test server. The server only can add CDM Domain.

I just need to My expectaion is wrong or right. If i wrong and you have some idead about my problem, please tell me some idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USERS and IIS_USRS group is permit access everyone. Evenif server don't know who is accessor. But Server don't know they. So try use guest account.
It is the reason return serverdomainname\guest.

My test server didn't participate in active directory.
So server never know about my localPC.

I make test server participate in active directory.
And add access permition domain on site.
And solved this problem.